# How can I return correctly a function for a phrasing with JSON?

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift

Recently I started a project using the API of CityBikes, which allows to have in real time the data of the bike sharing stations of different cities in the world (https://api.citybik.es/v2/).
As a first step I extracted the various links to get the data I need to receive the various information.
Then I created a function, extractStationData, which takes the links and adds them to the "base" link, allowing the parsing of the JSON and the reception of the various data. My problem comes at this point, since I can not add the data obtained before to the link through the function. 
How can I do that? Do I have to change the function with a return?

Here's the code:

```
    let networksURL = "https://api.citybik.es/v2/networks/"
    guard let dataURL = URL(string: networksURL) else {return}

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: dataURL) { (data, response, err) in

        guard let data = data else {return}
        let dataAsString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)

    guard let blog = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Blog.self, from: data) else {
        print("Error: Couldn't decode data")
        return
    }

    print("Networks link:")
    for article in blog.articles {
        print("- \(article.href)")
    }

        func extractStationData() {
            for article in blog.articles {
                article.href
            }
        }

        let stationDataURL = "https://api.citybik.es\(extractStationData())"
        guard let newDataURL = URL(string: stationDataURL) else {return}

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: newDataURL) { (data, response, err) in

            guard let data = data else {return}
            let dataAsStringForStation = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)

            guard let dataFromStation = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Datamain.self, from: data) else {
                print("Error: Couldn't decode station data")
                return
            }

            print("data:")
            for something in dataFromStation.qwerty {
                print("- \(something.empty_slots)")
                print("- \(something.free_bikes)")
                print("- \(something.name)")
                print("- \(something.latitude)")
                print("- \(something.longitude)")

            }

            }.resume()
}.resume()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code cannot work.

You have to separate the two tasks and use `DispatchGroup` to get notified when the network requests in the second task are finished.

First create a function for the main task with completion handler, I left out most of the code to show the workflow

```
func getMainData(completion: @escaping(Blog)->Void) {

  ...
  URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: dataURL) { (data, response, err) in 
     ...
     completion(blog)
  }

}
```

Call the function and perform the network requests depending on the main data in the completion handler

```
getMainData() { blog in 
    let group = DispatchGroup()
    for article in blog.articles {
        ...
        group.enter()
        // create newDataURL from article
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: newDataURL) { (data, response, err) in
           ...
            for something in dataFromStation.qwerty {
               print("- \(something.empty_slots)")
               print(" .... "
            }
            group.leave()
        }

    }
    group.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
        print("finished")
    }

}
```

However I recommend to load (only) the main data in a master view controller and the data for a selected location on demand in a detail view controller.

Comment: I don't think they are two independent API calls so you can not have them run in parallel, if you look at the second request param used for it is derived from the response of first API, so running them in parallel will result in second API failing all the time

Comment: @SandeepBhandari  The code in the question is a bit confusing. The main data returns an array of `articles`, each article contains an URL (the `href` thing) to load subsequent data. The most reasonable way to do that under control is `DispatchGroup`.

Comment: if OP is trying to load data for each article separately than it makes absolute sense to use DispatchGroup, but in his code it looks like he is loading data for all articles in a single API call in that case it does not make much difference if we use `DispatchGroup` as there is only one call :) But you are correct, code is confusing and can't conclude on excatly what OP is trying to achieve :)

Comment: @SandeepBhandari According to the JSON at given link there is clearly one network request per *article*.

Comment: woah, you checked that :O I concluded that looking at OP's code :) If thats the case I rest my case sir, OPs code needs more structuring then :)

Comment: @SandeepBhandari In comments I write very often *JSON is very easy to read*. That's not just a phrase, it's true 